How to Apply Dynamic Color based on device wallpaper in Custom Notification Layout Without Theming the Entire App?
I'm working on an Android app where I need to apply dynamic colors (Material You theming) to a custom notification layout. However, I don't want to theme the entire app—just the notification UI.
What I've Tried:
Setting colorPrimary, colorSecondary, etc., in custom themes.
Using RemoteViews to customize the notification layout and applying color programmatically.
Problem:
Despite these efforts, I am unable to apply dynamic color specifically to the custom notification without affecting the app's global theme or facing issues like Cannot resolve symbol 'colorPrimary'.
I need a solution to apply Material You's dynamic color to notifications without changing the theme of the whole app.
Is there a way to apply Material You dynamic color to only the custom notification layout in Android? Any code examples or detailed guidance would be highly appreciated.

Extract the dominant color from the device wallpaper using Palette.
import android.app.WallpaperManager
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable
import androidx.palette.graphics.Palette

fun getWallpaperColor(context: Context): Int? {
    val wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(context)
    val wallpaperDrawable = wallpaperManager.drawable

    if (wallpaperDrawable is BitmapDrawable) {
        val bitmap: Bitmap = wallpaperDrawable.bitmap
        val palette = Palette.from(bitmap).generate()
        return palette.getDominantColor(0)  // Get the dominant color or use other palette swatches
    }
    return null  // Default color if extraction fails
}


Apply the extracted color to specific views in the custom notification layout with RemoteViews.
<!-- res/layout/custom_notification.xml -->
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/notification_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Notification Title"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="@color/default_text_color" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/notification_message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/notification_title"
        android:text="Notification message"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textColor="@color/default_text_color" />
</RelativeLayout>


This approach only changes the notification layout's colors based on the wallpaper, leaving the rest of the app's theme unchanged.
import android.app.NotificationChannel
import android.app.NotificationManager
import android.app.PendingIntent
import android.app.NotificationCompat
import android.content.Context
import android.os.Build
import android.widget.RemoteViews
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat

fun createCustomNotification(context: Context) {
    val color = getWallpaperColor(context) ?: Color.BLUE  // Default color if none is extracted

    // Create custom view for notification
    val customView = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.custom_notification)
    customView.setTextColor(R.id.notification_title, color)
    customView.setTextColor(R.id.notification_message, color)

    val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "YOUR_CHANNEL_ID")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
        .setStyle(NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle())
        .setCustomContentView(customView)
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)

    // Create notification channel for Android O and above
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val channel = NotificationChannel(
            "YOUR_CHANNEL_ID",
            "Your Channel Name",
            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
        )
        context.getSystemService(NotificationManager::class.java).createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }

    // Show notification
    val notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context)
    notificationManager.notify(1, notificationBuilder.build())
}


